# How to check if the string in one table matches with string in another table and do some additional conditional expression?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two Tables:

```
**df1-- data1 = {'Company':['ADIDAS','NIKE','PUMA','NEW BALANCE','UNDER ARMOUR'],
   'Keywords':['COPA, PREDATOR, ORIGINALS, SPEEDFLOW','MERCURIAL, SUPERSTAR, VAPOR','ULTRA, FUTURE, RAPIDO','FURON','TEKELA'],
   'Suppliers':['', '', '[STADIUM, JD]', '', '']}


| Company    |Keywords                              | Suppliers   |
| ---------- |--------------------------------------|-------------|
| ADIDAS     |COPA, PREDATOR, ORIGINALS, SPEEDFLOW  | <NA>        |
| NIKE       |MERCURIAL, SUPERSTAR, VAPOR          | <NA>        |
| PUMA       |ULTRA, FUTURE, RAPIDO               |STADIUM, JD|
|NEW BALANCE |FURON                               | <NA>        |
|UNDER ARMOUR|TEKELA                              | <NA>        |

**df2 --data2 = {'Names':['ADIDAS PREDATOR 17.1','NIKE MERCURIAL 2020','NIKE VAPOR 2021','NEW BALANCE FURON','PUMA RAPIDO 21.3', 'PUMA RAPIDO 21.4'],
   'Supplier':['ADIDAS','NIKE','NIKE','JD','STADIUM', 'JD'], 'Company.1': ['', '', '', '', '', '']}**
| Names                | Supplier | Company1   |
| -------------------- | ---------|-----------|
| ADIDAS PREDATOR 17.1 |ADIDAS    | <NA>      |
| NIKE MERCURIAL 2020  |NIKE      | <NA>      |
| NIKE VAPOR 2021      |NIKE      | <NA>      |
| NEW BALANCE FURON    |JD        | <NA>      |
| PUMA RAPIDO 21.3     |STADIUM   | <NA>      |
| PUMA RAPIDO 21.4     |JD        | <NA>      |
```

**Logic:**

*First check if df2.Names has any df1.keywords.--If YES, check if df1.suppliers is empty----
`If Yes add df2.company1 as df1.company`---If NO, check if df2.supplier has any df1.suppliers.--
`IF Yes add df2.company1 as df1.company`*

**Expected Output:**

```
| Names                | Supplier | Company1 |
| -------------------- | ---------|-----------|
| ADIDAS PREDATOR 17.1 |ADIDAS    | ADIDAS    |
| NIKE MERCURIAL 2020  |NIKE      | NIKE      |
| NIKE VAPOR 2021      |NIKE      | NIKE      |
| NEW BALANCE FURON    |JD        | NEW BALANCE|
| PUMA RAPIDO 21.3     |STADIUM   | PUMA      |
```

**Code in Python**

```
for i in range(len(df1["Keywords"])):       
  for j in range(len(df1["Keywords"][i])):
    for name_index in range(len(df2["Product_name"])):
        # checking keywords
        if df1["Keywords"][i][j].strip() in df2["Product_name"][name_index]:  
                  
            # checking suppliers
            if df1["Suppliers"][i] == "NA"
                df2["Company.1"][name_index] = df1["Company"][i]  
            else:
                for suppliers in df1["Suppliers"][i]:                               
                    if df2["Supplier"][name_index] in suppliers:
                        df2["Company.1"][name_index] = df1["Company"][i]
                             break
```

Comment: Have you looked into using `SPLIT()` functions to create arrays for your names and keywords, and then using either a `LATERAL FLATTEN` to create joinable tables or `ARRAY_INTERSECTION` to see where arrays of names and keywords overlap?

Comment: Yes I've tried using SPLIT() (not for the names but for keywords).  I want to search for the keywords anywhere in the names so I think ARRAY_INTERSECTION will not be useful. I will surely try that as well.

Comment: I am thinking to create different rows for diferent keywords to reduce the complexity of problem. Then look for a string match between names and keywords. Any suggestion you can provide from the top of your head @MikeWalton?

Comment: If you split both names and keywords, then intersection would give you where any word matched any word.  Is that not useful?

Comment: Your idea for creating rows is what LATERAL FLATTEN would do after you do a SPLIT.  This would give you a word per row along with the original value, which you could then use to join to keywords that you've also executed a LATERAL FLATTEN / SPLIT on.  If I have some spare time, I can try and mock something up for you.

Comment: Oh okay! now I get it. That would be extremely useful! I will start working on those functions.